# Nested form not working to save client_id and user_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I have Users, Users have many Clients and Contacts. Clients also have many Contacts (a Contact belongs to both Users and Clients).

In my client view, I want to create a new Client and on the same form allow the user to create the first Contact for that client. Initially, I thought using nested attributes would do the trick but I'm running into some issues. When I go to save @client in clients_controller#create, I can't save because user_id can't be blank and client_id can't be blank for the Contact. Here's what I have so far:

clients controller index (where the new client form is located):

```
  def index
    @clients = current_user.clients
    @client = Client.new
    @contact = @client.contacts.build

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @clients }
    end
  end
```

and the create method:

```
  def create
    @client = current_user.clients.new(params[:client])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @client.save
```

and the form:

```
  = form_for(@client) do |f|
          = f.fields_for(:contacts) do |contact|
```

but when I go to save it requires a client_id and user_id...but I can't really set those using the nested attributes. how can I accomplish this? is there a better way of doing this? here's my params:

```
{"name"=>"asdf", "contacts_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>"asdf", "email"=>"asdf@gmail.com"}}}
```

I just tried adding the missing values directly into the contacts_attributes but since @client hasn't been saved yet, I can't assign the client.id to contact:

```
params[:client][:contacts_attributes]["0"].merge!(:user_id => current_user.id)
params[:client][:contacts_attributes]["0"].merge!(:client_id => @client.id)
```

even when user_id is set...it still says user is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add `accepts_nested_attributes_for` to your model? You need something like this:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contacts
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :contacts
end
```

Also, you should be using `build` in your create action:

```
@client = current_user.clients.build(params[:client])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my setup that worked for your example:

`app/models/user.rb`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :clients_attributes

  has_many :clients

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :clients
end
```

`app/models/client.rb`:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :company, :contacts_attributes

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :contacts

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :contacts
end
```

`app/models/contact.rb`:

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email

  belongs_to :client
end
```

`app/controllers/users_controller.rb`:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  # ...

  def new
    @user    = User.new
    @client  = @user.clients.build
    @concact = @client.contacts.build

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @user }
    end
  end

  # ...
end
```

The actual form:

```
<% # app/views/users/new.erb %>

<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.fields_for :clients do |client_form| %>
      <h5>Client</h5>
      <%= client_form.label :company, "Company name" %>
      <%= client_form.text_field :company %>

      <div class="field">
        <h5>Contact</h5>
        <%= client_form.fields_for :contacts do |contact_form| %>
          <%= contact_form.label :email %>
          <%= contact_form.text_field :email %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The form looks like this:

[image]

Here's how params sent by forms look like:

```
{
  "utf8"=>"✓",
  "authenticity_token" => "bG6Lv62ekvK7OS86Hg/RMQe9S0sUw0iB4PCiYnsnsE8=",
  "user" => {
    "name" => "My new user",
    "clients_attributes" => {
      "0" => {
        "company" => "Client's Company Name LLC",
        "contacts_attributes" => {
          "0" => {
            "email" => "emailbox@client.com"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "commit" => "Create User"
}
```

**Update**

To enable adding more companies/contacts afterwards, change the `UsersController#edit` action to this:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  # ...

  def edit
    @client  = current_user.clients.build
    @concact = @client.contacts.build

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @user }
    end
  end

  # ...
end
```

Comment: What if I don't want to do this through the user model? I'm not creating a new user every time...only a new Client and Contact.

Comment: hmm..is going through the @user model absolutely necessary? it just seems wrong to me since contact is more closely related to client (i think?). is there a way without user? especially since the view and routes are both in Client right now.

Answer (score 0):

The following validations may be causing this problem since the parent id has not assigned to a child object at the time the validations are run for it. The workaround to this is to either remove these validations or set them to run on update only. This way you lose out on these validations for the create method but it works.

```
# client.rb
validates :user, presence: true

# contact.rb
validates :client, presence: true
```